# Configure react redux middleware from fetch

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a Redux middleware that requires some data to be configured via a server call (eg, `fetch`) which is async / requires promises.

However, every example of `createStore`[such as this one](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/main.js) seems to use a Singleton pattern for the store.  This means that the store gets initialized before my fetch is complete.  Because it's middleware, I can't "reconfigure" it after createStore is called.

How can i configure `createStore` without using a singleton pattern to configure middleware?

Answer (score 1):

How do you fetch those data? If it's just a simple API call. You can easily wait for the data to be returned then pass the data to createStore. Something like this:

```
const fetchData = () => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    data: 'Your data here'
  });
}

const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
fetchData()
  .then((data) => {
    initialState.somethingYouNeed = data;
    const store = createStore(initialState);
    // Do the rest here
  });
```

Comment: I am using react-router-redux and it requires a reference to the store to call `syncHistoryWithStore`.  How would I get that store reference to my router?  Most cases rely on the singleton implementation to do this.

Comment: Currently, I'm follow this example. Still there are quite a lot issues in the example. But it's a very nice boilerplate. You can find the answer in. https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example